# How does automatic updating of controls work, when DataRow is updated?

Tags: .net, data-binding

When a change is made to a `DataRow` instance, the controls it is bound to are updated automatically. How does this work? I'd like to implement something similar for an own class that I bind to a `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what I was looking for: I simply have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the container (like a `BindingList<T>`) of changes.

BTW: `DataRow` seems to work a little different and does not implement this interface.